# metrics from prom files are not showing on the metrics list on Node Exporter

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I followed [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1686/how-to-install-prometheus-node-exporter-on-ubuntu-2004) article to setup node exporter and node_exporter.service looks like below

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter --collector.textfile=/home/rafa/prom_files/result.prom --collector.textfile.directory=/home/rafa/prom_files

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can access the metrics, using `IP:9100/metrics` but I don't see the metrics as part of the `result.prom` available along with the rest.

result.prom looks like below and there is an empty line at the last of the file.

```
frontend_image_processing_status 1
frontend_Negative_publication_status 1
frontend_Sabre_publication_status 0
frontend_Negative_scan_time 0:00:07
```

What am I missing here ? Thank you !

Comment: Afaik, option `--collector.textfile` doesn't exist, you should use `--collector.textfile.directory`. What is shown in the logs of your service? Have you tried to run `/usr/local/bin/node_exporter --collector.textfile.directory=/home/rafa/prom_files` manually?

Comment: expected float as value, got \"0:00:07\"" from `frontend_Negative_scan_time 0:00:07`

Comment: Error - `prom_files/result.prom\": text format parsing error in line 4: expected float as value, got \"0:00:07\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in the last line of your `result.prom`:

```
frontend_Negative_scan_time 0:00:07
```

Exposed Prometheus' metrics have to be of the format:

```
metric_name [
  "{" label_name "=" `"` label_value `"` { "," label_name "=" `"` label_value `"` } [ "," ] "}"
] value
```

Where `value` of the type float (or any of `NaN`, `+Inf`, `-Inf`)

More on metrics format in [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/).

Best solution for this situation: change you metric to store scan duration in second.

Also, consider renaming your metric to `frontend_negative_scan_duration_seconds` per [best naming practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/) recommended by Prometheus. Or even `frontend_scan_duration_seconds{result="negative"}` depending on meaning of `negative` in your context.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation..